# sql order by date before selection query help

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm about to jump into some SQL query code that I haven't attempted before, basically my tables will have rows with dates that will not be in order, what I want to do is firstly order the table by date, then select 9 rows that will be older than a specified date.

So the query I'm considering running will look something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                         FROM links 
                     ORDER BY date DESC 
                        WHERE date < '$olderdate' 
                        LIMIT 9");
```

will this work? or is there a better way of pulling this off?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? You already wrote the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the `WHERE` clause before the `ORDER BY` one:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from links where date<'$olderdate' order by date desc limit 9");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use order by after where condition

select * from links where date<'$olderdate' order by date desc limit 9